# Plotting custom logistic distribution

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic-distribution

I'm trying to understand the logistic distribution and its application in a sports scoring model.

The CDF of the logistic distribution is:

$F(x) = {1 \over 1 + e^{-(x-\mu) / s}}$

I can then use `stat_function(fun = dlogis())` in `ggplot` to create plot showing the distribution. So far so good.

Now I have the following equation for the logistic distribution in a proposed scoring system:

$F(x) = {1 \over 1 + ce^{dx'}}$

*c* is simply a small constant for where the line is crossing y at x = 0.

But how is *d* related to $-(x-\mu) / s$? And how can I use the second function in `stat_function()`?

Somehow *d* must be related to the location and scale parameters, but I can't quite figure out how...

Comment: This is simple algebra. I hope it's not homework. $1/F - 1 = ce^{dx} = e^{\ln c + dx} = e^{−(x−μ)/s} = e^{−x/s+μ/s}$  ... so $d = -1/s$ and  $\ln c = \mu/s$ or $c=e^{\mu/s}$.

Comment: Thanks a heap! No, I wish I was a student and could do this for homework. But it's just me trying to get my head around stuff that perhaps should have stuck a long time ago. This is really helpful!!

Comment: Given your algebra is a bit rusty, I should probably have made sure to emphasize that $1/F-1$ means $(1/F)-1$ not $1/(F-1)$ by ordinary precedence of operations. (This stuff is not really statistics as such, or I'd have posted an answer)